# AWS glue: ignoring spaces in JSON properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a dataset with JSON files in it. Some of the entries of these JSONs have spaces in the entries like

```
{
    'propertyOne': 'something',
    'property Two': 'something'
}
```

I've had this data set crawled by several different crawlers to try and get the schema I want. For some reason on one of my crawls, the spaces were removed, but on trying to replicate the process, I cannot get the spaces to be removed and when querying in Athena I get this error

```
HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: : expected at position x in 'some string' but ' ' found instead.
```

Position x is the position of the space between 'property' and 'Two' in the JSON entry.

I would like to just be able to exclude this field or have the space removed when crawled, but I'm not sure how.  I can't change the JSON format. Any help is appreiated

Comment: I think you may be misdiagnosing the problem.  Space after `:` is valid JSON.  Single-quotes `'` for strings are not valid JSON.  JSON requires `"`.

Comment: I'm surprised that whitespace causes such a problem for Glue. It feels like they need to support spaces in property names because many different data sources could be using this and it might be too much effort to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your only option, in this case, would be to create your own [custom JSON classifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-json) to select only those attributes you want the Crawler to add to the Data Catalog.

I.e. if you want to only retrieve propertyOne you can use specify the JSONPath expression as `$.propertyOne`.

Note also that your JSON should be in double quotes, the single quotes could also be causing issues when parsing the data.

Comment: The JSON can get rather bulky in size and thats why I like having the crawler identify the schema. Would it be better to instead 'clean' the data beforehand with AWS Lambda and remove the spaces instead?

Comment: Sure, you could have a Lambda which is invoked when data is uploaded to S3 to clean the JSON, and then run the Crawler afterwards :)

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing now, but it also means that you can't query your raw input data, which is a little frustrating

Answer (score 1):

this is actually a bug with aws gule json classifier because it doesn't play nice with nested properties that have spaces in them. The syntax error is in the schema generated by the crawler, not in the json. It generates something like this:

```
struct<propertyOne:string, property Two:string>
```

The space in "property two" should have been escaped, by the crawler. At this point, generating the DDL for the table is also not working. We are also facing this issue and looking for workarounds

Comment: You mentioned that this was a bug, is this something that AWS is working to fix?